# Can javascript in an html running on the Android set the alarm time of Android?

Tags: javascript, android, alarmmanager

Can javascript in an html running on the Android get access to alarm manager interface ?

Answer (score -1):

Of course yes.

Js and android can invoke each other'methods  well.

Comment: Not familiar with IOS,sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I think it is possible.

```
@JavascriptInterface
 public boolean invokeAlarmManager() {
    //Do whatever you need with AlarmManager
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me the code corresponding to "mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);"?